# View not updating before automatic Segue away from itself

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, segue

Essentially I have a view controller where the user picks from three choices.  Once the user chooses something, the view segues away to another view controller that displays some information regarding their choice for about 5 seconds and then segues back to original view controller automatically where the User must make more choices... (its basically a loop until something is accomplished).

The problem I am having is when the User touches their option, it seems to just segue back to itself without ever displaying the intermediary screen.  I added a sleep(5); to the viewDidLoad but all that causes it to do is pause on the original choice screen for 5 seconds before segueing to itself.  I also put in an NSLog in just to make sure it was actually using the new controller, which it is indeed.

I didn't include code since its so trivial. viewDidLoad on the new controller, has sleep(5) and the call to segue back to the original view controller.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by moving the code to viewDidAppear.  Should have done that from the beginning honestly, just didn't think it through enough I guess.